# Halstead Science Metrics

Tags: java, parsing, javaparser

I am working in building `halstead Metrics` in java and I am using `javaparser` library and I am confusing about how I can find all java reserved words in the java imported file which will be parsing to find the operator (n1) ?

Comment: Do you understand what the AST actually contains?  If so, why are you concerned about "finding reserved words"?  (Hmm, this question seems rather stale.  Is OP still interested in a response?)

Answer (score -1):

You might be better to use ANTLR to do this - I provided details in response to another question here - [building halstead metrics in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21652079/building-halstead-metrics-in-java)?

Comment: And what exactly is the justification that "ANTLR might be better"?  Apparantly the javaparser library parses Java 1.5, produces trees and provides visitor support. That should be plenty to support a metrics tool. ANTLR might be OK, but which parser isn't apparantly part of OP's problem.

Comment: I just answered this question because I was answering the other question and Stackoverflow asked me to 'be nice' and answer another question. Personally I think ANTLR is 'better' than javaparser if you are building a parser - mainly because it gives you more freedom in relation to designing the grammar based on the latest version - I thought, like you, that javaparser only supported 1.5 but I see it now supports 1.8.